# How to implement a timer to stop Shutil copytree

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil

How can I implement a timer in my script so that the shutil copytree function will only run and copy files for a certain amount of seconds and then either stop the script or do something else?

Comment: I might be wrong here, but this smells a little of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You could write a wrapper function (that calls `shutil.copy2` and does some additional checks - like time it took since it was 1st invoked) and pass it as the *copy\_function* argument (that way it will be called for each file that is being copied).

Answer (score 1):

Directly, you can't.

Indirectly, you can just [take the code for `shutil.copytree` from source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/shutil.py#L168), because it's pretty simple, and add time-limiting to it.

Be advised that you're going to end up with an incomplete copy if you stop copying at an arbitrary point.